# how to remove autocomplete with in a text box

Tags: php, html

I need to remove autocomplete in all the textbox with in my page
 so I have given <`input name="txt_username" id="txt_username" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off" /></dd></dl>`

But it's not working does anyone know this?

Comment: If the auto-complete is coming from your browser, it might be hard to disable this...

Comment: it is coming only on crome or in all browsers

Comment: may i know what is </dd></dl> ? and what is the browser that you have tested it on

Answer (score 10):

Autocomplete, unless you're doing something crazy with AJAX, is a client-side thing and you can't always control it like that.

Since autocomplete works by caching your previous entries for a **specific input text name**, many banks randomly generate the input text name *at each form page load* but keep track of what is generated either somewhere else in a hidden input element or on the server side.

So instead of

```
<input name="txt_username" id="txt_username" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off" />
```

It might be something like

```
<input type="text" name="f6Lx571p" id="txt_username"/>
<input type="hidden" name="username_key" value="f6Lx571p" />
```

And the server-side code adjusted accordingly.  For example, PHP code might have looked like:

```
<?php
$user = $_POST['txt_username'];
...
```

but it would have to be changed to something like:

```
<?php
$user = $_POST[$_POST['username_key']];
...
```

Its a bit annoying, but it works.

Comment: I have to agree, your answer is the better way. +1

Answer (score 4):

Autocomplete cannot be turned off, it's something from the browser, but I think this must help:`<input type="password" name="password" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly')">`

Comment: easiest trick.. works on firefox.. can't try on other browsers...

Answer (score 3):

You can also try placing that `autocomplete` attribute on the form element.

```
<form id="myForm" autocomplete="off">
  ...
</form>
```

This will probably invalidate your HTML so you might want to consider adding this attribute dynamically with JavaScript.

Comment: I recommend trying the [other](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10411283/558021) [suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10411247/558021) methods first...

Answer (score 3):

Autocomplete cannot be turned off, it's something from the browser. What I do if I want to turn off autocomplete is the following:

Start a session with a field name and random number:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['strUsername'] = "username_" . mt_rand(0, 1000000);
```

Now use this variable as the field's name:

```
name="' . $_SESSION['strUsername'] . '" id="txt_username" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off" /></dd></dl>
```

To check the value of the field simply use

```
$username = $_POST[$_SESSION['strUsername']];
```

Now, the name will be random everytime, so the browser will not recognize the field and will not give the autocompletion.

Comment: This is good, but requires the use of sessions, see my answer for a way to eliminate this.